# Flipping macOS metal texture

Tags: macos, metal, metalkit

What is the best way to horizontally flip a texture in macOS metal?

I can use the following vertex shader and successfully flip the texture, but this code doesn't work (crashes) on older Macs (< 2015).

I could flip the texture before I submit it to the GPU but that seems very inefficient. I also checked the documentation. I can't see any way to change the anchor position from being the left top of the texture.

```
// Vertex Function
vertex RasterizerData
vertexShader(uint vertexID [[ vertex_id ]],
             constant AAPLVertex *vertexArray [[ buffer(AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices) ]],
             constant vector_uint2 *viewportSizePointer  [[ buffer(AAPLVertexInputIndexViewportSize) ]])

{

    RasterizerData out;

    vertexArray[vertexID].position.y *= -1;
    // Index into our array of positions to get the current vertex
    //   Our positions are specified in pixel dimensions (i.e. a value of 100 is 100 pixels from
    //   the origin)
    float2 pixelSpacePosition = vertexArray[vertexID].position.xy;

    // Get the size of the drawable so that we can convert to normalized device coordinates,
    float2 viewportSize = float2(*viewportSizePointer);

    // The output position of every vertex shader is in clip space (also known as normalized device
    //   coordinate space, or NDC). A value of (-1.0, -1.0) in clip-space represents the
    //   lower-left corner of the viewport whereas (1.0, 1.0) represents the upper-right corner of
    //   the viewport.

    // In order to convert from positions in pixel space to positions in clip space we divide the
    //   pixel coordinates by half the size of the viewport.
    out.clipSpacePosition.xy = pixelSpacePosition / (viewportSize / 2.0);

    // Set the z component of our clip space position 0 (since we're only rendering in
    //   2-Dimensions for this sample)
    out.clipSpacePosition.z = 0.0;

    // Set the w component to 1.0 since we don't need a perspective divide, which is also not
    //   necessary when rendering in 2-Dimensions
    out.clipSpacePosition.w = 1.0;

    // Pass our input textureCoordinate straight to our output RasterizerData. This value will be
    //   interpolated with the other textureCoordinate values in the vertices that make up the
    //   triangle.
    out.textureCoordinate = vertexArray[vertexID].textureCoordinate;

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Just so we're clear on terminology: as they're ordinarily used, the phrases "flip horizontally" and "flip vertically" mean "flip about the vertical axis (left and right swap places)" and "flip about the horizontal axis (top and bottom swap places)", respectively. Since you're negating the y coordinate, I assume what we're discussing is a vertical flip, according to these definitions.

Comment: In any case, if you want to flip the texture, is there a reason you can't manipulate the texture coordinates to do so? either setting `out.textureCoordinate.y = 1 - out.textureCoordinate.y` or `out.textureCoordinate.y = -out.textureCoordinate.y` will have the effect of flipping vertically; the former is more common since the mapping is more intuitive. If you use the latter, you should ensure that you're using a repeating address mode on your sampler or sampler state.

Comment: Incidentally I'm curious exactly what kind of crash you see on older Macs and whether that behavior is tied to particular versions of macOS.

Comment: Your recommendation works. Will try on another older system tomorrow. Flipping the vertices is what caused a crash on a 2014 Mac mini.

Comment: These occurred on Mojave.